# FuelPHP - Why is there a backslash in this code: $email = \Email::forge();

Tags: fuelphp

Why is there a backslash in this code?

```
$email = \Email::forge();
```

I am reading over the [Email package documentation](http://ensembleacteon.com/acteon_admin/docs/packages/email/methods.html) on FuelPHPs site. The above code is their example. Why is there a backslash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the class is declared in global namespace and seems to be used in some other namespace, where it's required.

Here's complete manual about namespaces:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Even if the code that uses it is also in the global namespace, it's still good practice to prefix it, so it's clear where the class is loaded from.